# How to mock an instance method on injected instance of the class under test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock, micronaut, micronaut-test

I am trying to mock an instance method within a real object which is injected within my Test class in `spock` and I am using Micronaut (with Java) for writing my application. It is as follows:

```
class MyTestClass extends Specification {
    @Subject
    @Inject
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest

    Event sampleEvent = getMockEvent();

    def "test1" () {
       given:
       def classUnderTestSpy = Spy(classUnderTest)

       when:
       def res = classUnderTestSpy.callTestMethod(sampleEvent)

       then:
       1 * classUnderTestSpy.isRunning(_ as Long) >> {
           return false
       }
       res != null
    }

    def getMockEvent() {
       new Event(/* Some attributes here */)
    }
}
```

The `ClassUnderTest` is something like this:

```java
@Singleton
class ClassUnderTest {
    @Inject
    Class1 class1Instance;

    @Value("${com.myapplication.property}")
    Integer value;


    Object callTestMethod(Event event) {
       // Some code
       boolean isRunning = isRunning(event.id);
       // Rest of the code
    }

    public boolean isRunning(Long id) {
        return SomeOtherClass.staticMethod(id);
    }
}
```

Whenever the `isRunning` method is called the real `SomeOtherClass.staticMethod()` method call happens and the `isRunning` method returns true not false. Is there anyway I can `Spy` the injected `ClassUnderTest` instance and mock the instance method?

Comment: Why did you delete your [identical original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75158979/1082681) including all the comments urging you to improve the question? With information hiding and duplicate questions you are not going to make lots of friends here.

Answer (score 1):

Again, cannot reproduce your issue.

Based on your example, I did the following and the test passes:

```
@MicronautTest //Your example is missing this, cannot even test without it
class SpyTest extends Specification{

    @Subject
    @Inject
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest

    Event sampleEvent = getMockEvent();

    def "Spy Test"() {
        given:
        def classUnderTestSpy = Spy(classUnderTest)

        when:
        def results = classUnderTestSpy.callTestMethod(sampleEvent)

        then:
//        1 * classUnderTestSpy.isRunning(_ as Long) >> false //Preferred Groovy/Spock way
        1 * classUnderTestSpy.isRunning(_ as Long) >> {
            println("I am returning the correct thing!")
            false
        }
        results == "Is something running: false"
    }

    def getMockEvent() {
        new Event("Is something running: ")
    }
}
```

```java
@Singleton
public class ClassUnderTest {
    private final InjectedClass iClass; //Noise in the example, not used

    public ClassUnderTest(InjectedClass iClass) { //Preferred way to inject
        this.iClass = iClass;
    }

    public String callTestMethod(Event event) {
        System.out.println("ClassUnderTest callTestMethod");
        boolean running = isRunning(0L);
        return event.message() + running;
    }

    public boolean isRunning(Long id) {
        System.out.println("ClassUnderTest isRunning with ID: " + id);
        return SomeOtherClass.staticMethod();
    }
}
```

```java
@Singleton
public class InjectedClass {
    public String info() {
        return "I was injected";
    }
}
```

```java
public record Event(String message) {}
```

```java
@Singleton
public class SomeOtherClass {
    public static boolean staticMethod() {
        System.out.println("SomeOtherClass Static Method called");
        throw new RuntimeException("Should never get called");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `InjectedClass`  is not related to the question, I just wanted to show the pattern of my class. AndI want to mock `isRunning` instance method of `ClassUnderTest`.

Comment: I am confused. How is your example mocking `isRunning` and mine isn't?

Comment: Exactly, the mock `classUnderTestSpy.isRunning(_ as Long) >>` is not working there even if I have used `Spy`. That's why I am asking can we mock the method `isRunning` method on the injected class instance?

Comment: Short answer is that you should be able to. Are you saying that you tried out my example in a new Micronaut project and the test does **NOT** pass? Without a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard to say what your issue is.

Comment: The example you have written will run successfully but in my case as you can see `class1Instance ` is injected, I cannot create a constructor to my class. So when I I will create `Spy` of `ClassUnderTest`,  the `class1Instance` will be null which I do not want